# Book for Linear Algebra and Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, book-recommendation

my major is Electrical Engineering and I am new in linear algebra and I need to be familiar with matrix theory deeply because of my research topic which is Image Processing. But, I do not know from where should I start. I would like to study a book to find out which part of the matrix theory is useful for my research area. Can anybody suggest an easy and easy-to-read book for linear algebra and matrix theory? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linear Algebra by Hoffman Kunze is a great book for beginners.

Then if you want to learn more about algebra I would suggest :

1)Artin's Algebra

2)Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote

Comment: What do Artin, Dummit and Foote have to do with the question about learning matrix algebra for image processing?

Comment: I am saying that if the OP gets some interest in algebra he/she can try these books further @1999

Answer (score 0):

The book "Linear Algebra" by Hoffmann and Kunze is a really good book. However, you can try "Linear Statistical Inference" by C.R. Rao as well. It is a pretty short encyclopaedia on a lot of topics in matrix algebra, although it is difficult to read and has some really hard problems.

In fact, you can go through "Matrix Algebra from a Statistician's Perspective". It has some comprehensive topics on the subject of interest.

Comment: All of them are very good books. what about part 2 of Zill's book. It seems to be a very easy-to-read book. but I do not know whether it is useful for me or it helps me to catch basic concepts rather than useful concepts.

Comment: Sorry, I have not read Zill.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Gilbert Strang's [Linear algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030105676). He also has video lectures [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/).

If you have never encountered matrices before, or want to revise, you should start with this book by [Eves](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cMLCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&dq=elementary+theory+of+matrices&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tzOYVbKPEdihugSSiZnoDw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=elementary%20theory%20of%20matrices&f=false)

Comment: Thank you, having video lecture notes can help a lot. but it seems that he does not start from basic and I should know some of linear algebra to catch the points.

Comment: @David see edit